# How did Marty know Doc originally?

Tags: back-to-the-future

It's clear that Marty first met the 1955 version of Doc by tracking his house down in the phone directory. However, earlier in the film, they are shown to have quite a strong relationship. Doc is happy with Marty coming into his house and even invites him to let himself in.

> **Doc:** This is very important. I forgot my video camera. Can you stop by and pick it up on your way to the Mall?

The fact that they spend time together seems to be common knowledge, to the extent that even the principal of Marty's school says that Marty is "still hanging around" with Doc.

> **Strickland:** Am I to understand that you are still hanging around with Doctor Emmett Brown, McFly?

But how did they get to know each other initially? Their hardly of a similar age and Marty doesn't seem to have any real interest in science or Doc's inventions. Why would he be involved with Doc in the first place?

Comment: Asked and answered on Movies.SE: https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/11206/46980

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like in [SE.movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/11207/70897):

> We never explained it in the movie. But the history of the characters that Bob Zemeckis and I created is this:
>
> > For years, Marty was told that Doc Brown was dangerous, a crackpot, a lunatic. So, being a red-blooded American teenage boy, age 13 or 14, he decided to find out just why this guy was so dangerous. **Marty snuck into Doc’s lab, and was fascinated by all the cool stuff that was there. when Doc found him there, he was delighted to find that Marty thought he was cool and accepted him for what he was.**
> >
> > Both of them were the black sheep in their respective environments. **Doc gave Marty a part-time job to help with experiments, tend to the lab, tend to the dog, etc.**
>
> And that’s the origin of their relationship.
>
> <sub>– [According](http://mentalfloss.com/article/28526/back-future-co-creator-bob-gale-explains-how-marty-and-doc-became-friends) to Bob Gale co-writer/producer</sub>